# Result Set to Multi Hash Map

Tags: java, database, performance

I have a situation here. I have a huge database with >10 columns and millions of rows. I am using a matching algorithm which matches each input records with the values in database.

The database operation is taking lot of time when there are millions of records to match. I am thinking of using a multi-hash map or any resultset alternative so that i can save the whole table in memory and prevent hitting database again....

Can anybody tell me what should i do??

Comment: I doubt that bringing millions of records to memory to give them treatment is going to be faster than manipulating the data in the db server itself and then just bring the results. Why don't you do it in the db server? That's its specialty after all.

Comment: First, identify where the bottleneck is. It could be the SQL query, the transfer of data between the database and the application, or building the result set objects. Try running the SQL first on the database independently of your application. A properly optimized query and database should have no trouble searching millions of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the right way to go. You are trying to do the database's work manually in Java. I'm not saying that you are not capable of doing this, but most databases have been developed for many years and are quite good in doing exactly the thing that you want.

However, databases need to be **configured correctly** for a given type of query to be executed fast. So my suggestion is that you first check whether you can tweak the database configuration to improve the performance of the query. The most common thing is to add the right indexes to your table. Read [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html) or the corresponding part of the manual of your particular database for more information.

The other thing is, if you have so much data storing everything in main memory is probably not faster and might even be infeasible. Not to say that you have to transfer the whole data first.

In any case, try to use a profiler to identify the bottleneck of the program first. Maybe the problem is not even on the database side.

Comment: Cool. I'll go through SQL SERVER/ORACLE indexes then